# gksu doesn't show the installed program folders into wine folder

Tags: permissions, wine

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS.

I tried to edit some specific parameters of an specific Windows software (which must be used with Wine), so I used gksu to open the ".wine" folders with root privileges (It is the only one way to change those parameters, because this software doesn't use the typical "Application Data" folder for the parameters).

But... I discovered that gksu doesn't show any installed software folder into the ".wine" "program files (x86)" folder.

Is it normal? Or... Is there something wrong into my PC?

Can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you really should not be running wine as root, it is a security risk to do so, see [Is installing wine in Ubuntu safe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175336/is-installing-wine-in-ubuntu-safe) and [Risks/Disadvantages associated with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49255/risks-disadvantages-associated-with-wine) and links.

Therefore, `~/.wine` should be owned by your user and you can modify file in ~/.wine without running as root or using gksu

Second , gksu is depreciated, see [When to use pkexec vs. gksu/gksudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo) and [What is the difference between "gksudo nautilus" and "sudo nautilus"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus/11766#11766) for some discussion.

The "problem" you are having is that gksu is setting `$HOME` as /root and thus you are editing /root/.wine rather then your /home/$USER/.wine .

The above links review this as does https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo, specifically https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells

See also [What is the difference between gksudo and gksu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21033/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-and-gksu)