# Is it secure to run windows application on linux?

Tags: security, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Risks/Disadvantages associated with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49255/risks-disadvantages-associated-with-wine)

I wanted to run windows applications on ubuntu. So i installed winehq. My question is that, is it secure to run windows applications on linux? Will my computer become vulnerable to virus??

Answer (score 3):

Linux itself will not be vulnerable as long as you don't do something silly like give it access to /.

Wine on the other hand is still susceptible to viruses, since it is designed to emulate a Windows environment, however in many cases it is different enough that most nasty code will not have much affect.

Maybe install clam-av and use that to make sure your /home and especially the Cdrive folder stays clean.

You're probably very safe if you don't use Windows internet and social media apps - and you don't really need to because there are good ones available for Ubuntu.

Comment: The last section of the WINE FAQ "Risks" is a little more detailed here: http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-1c91cac836dd52754c846d2ef62be4f346eebe87

Answer (score 0):

as already said, your linux distro is completely safe... Wine does not emulate windows. Only the required APIs to start most of the programs. If you think your wine version contains a virus just reinstall it but be sure to delete your personal wine files before reinstalling...

Comment: The wine documentation says otherwise.