# What are the implications of installing WINE while booting from a liveDVD?

Tags: wine, games

For various personal reasons I want to use a liveDVD for some tasks which include playing a game that works with WINE.

I will be using Ubuntu or Mint because I am most familiar with those.

Questions are:

If I install WINE will my Linux be like a Windows in the sense that I will be infected as easily as visiting a shady website or that my Linux will auto-execute viruses that are made for Windows? (The following paragraph is related to this.)

I observed that Linux in LiveDVD is always in super user mode or at least doesn't require passwords for tasks. How can I change that to either require a password or to exit super user mode? Or if it's a liveDVD then will it remain that way?

Finally if I install WINE and decide to play the game, will it break the NTFS drive the game was installed on in a Windows machine? I know it will probably break the game so I made another copy of it but both are on an NTFS drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Risks/Disadvantages associated with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49255/risks-disadvantages-associated-with-wine)

Answer (score 1):

> If I install WINE will my Linux be like a Windows in the sense that I will be infected as easily as visiting a shady website

Yes. Even more so if you use MSIE inside WINE. With 1 remark: you can get infected with rootkits and other malware intended to infect Linux. It has a very very low probability but it is possible.

> or that my Linux will auto-execute viruses that are made for Windows?

No. Linux can not execute scripts made for Windows. It can execute scripts that are made to run on Linux.

> I  observed that Linux in LiveDVD is always in super user mode or at least doesn't require passwords for tasks. How can I change that to either require a password or to exit super user mode? Or if it's a liveDVD then will it remain that way?

The live session is intended to test your system for hardware compatibility  and a general idea how Ubuntu works, install Ubuntu or do admin tasks to repair your system. It is not for general usage. All bets are of when you want to use WINE inside a live session.

What you want is a "persistent live Ubuntu USB" ( [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb) )

> Finally if I install WINE and decide to play the game, will it break the NTFS drive the game was installed on in a Windows machine? I know it will probably break the game so I made another copy of it but both are on an NTFS drive.

All bets are of when it comes to Windows related software. That includes WINE but also SAMBA. Even with a normal installation those should be avoided.

Comment: On the first question: if I am not stupid to run Internet Explorer in WINE, but only run the game in WINE + I am browsing with the pre-installed Firefox program WITHOUT WINE then do the shady sites have a chance? Also did you personally encounter some problems with NTFS partition breaking under Linux use?

Comment: No and no. Ntfs is as stable as always. Only thing linux does not like about it is the hibernate it can do.