# Wine - Security risks - Dofus warns it's being run by administrator

Tags: permissions, wine, security, games

Not having the ability to install a game (which I appreciate a lot) in a classic way (normal Linux installation), I decided to use Wine (wine-stable).

First I heard that Wine is not a security risk because it's a virtualization, or something like that, I did not know much about how Wine works.

But are there really no risks? (I doubt that risk 0 does not exist) For example with an elevation of permissions or something like that?

What makes me slightly afraid is this message, I use Wine without using `sudo` (`wine dofus.exe`), but here is the message, Wine uses `sudo` by default? Should I be afraid of this message? I do not intend to install other games or suspicious programs with Wine, but only the one that I think does not have a virus, it is Dofus, despite all this message makes me ask questions and given that I do not know Wine, I would like to have your opinion

[image: This application is running as Administrator (Image)]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/49255/risks-disadvantages-associated-with-wine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use wine for programs like you used windows. Programs from unknown sources will introduce you to security problems.

Wine is not windows, so not all programs are running flawlessly. For accurate info on your program look up it in the winehq.org application database.

Your computer will be as secure as you behave. If you are running programs from unknown sources, the only you can blame is you.

Never use `sudo` with wine, there is no reason to do that. When you have permission problem on accessing peripherals or files, use chmod command to allow user access to certain devices or files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kukulo, this is a game I use on Windows, but it is extremely popular, and I do not think it is malicious (https://www.dofus.com/) And concerning `sudo`, I did not use `sudo` to run the game (just `wine dofus.exe`), but I still get the warning of this game that you could see in picture.

Comment: I would tick the checkbox and hit continue. In wine there are no elevated permissions for linux. It might detect the administrator permissions for wine programs, but not for linux.