# I'm whining about wine, windows and linux

Tags: wine, viruses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if I run a virus/trojan Windows EXE on Ubuntu with Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5031/what-if-i-run-a-virus-trojan-windows-exe-on-ubuntu-with-wine)

If I run a program that's windows (exe) on a linux system, find out that it was infected with a virus, will it just crash the program or somehow make my system in-stable?

I'm assuming that it wouldn't harm my system at all, because my OS is linux and the windows executable cannot run on mine--but then wine does it...