# Can Ubuntu/Linux machines be infected by the Shylock trojan?

Tags: skype, malware

I've heard of this [trojan that can now spread through Skype](http://news.techworld.com/security/3421297/shylock-banking-malware-can-now-spread-via-skype-researchers-say/). I use Skype regularly and also access my online banking account occasionally on my machine. Should I be worried? I also run ClamAV and a firewall. I'm on 12.04. What steps can this noob take to gain further protection?

Comment: It says it works by sending messages and files out of common sense you would ask your contacts if they did so and avoid that entirely.

Answer (score 4):

No, no Linux system can be affected. Please see:

http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2012-082310-2840-99

*"Systems Affected: Windows 98, Windows 95, Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows Me, Windows Vista, Windows NT, Windows 2000"*

Wine cannot affect Linux, because it is a virtual XP, meaning that the "Windows" folder (made by wine, because some Win applications need resources from there) is fake. Even if the virus does change things in the fake "Windows" folder, it does not affect Linux.

Comment: What about Wine?

Comment: Regarding Wine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5031/what-if-i-run-a-virus-trojan-windows-exe-on-ubuntu-with-wine Basically: no since the virus needs to specifically be written to targer wine.

Comment: "Wine cannot affect Linux, because it is a virtual XP, meaning that the "Windows" folder (made by wine, because some Win applications need resources from there) is fake." - You might want to change the wording, I'm sure Wine it's not a virtual *Windows Xp* and the Wine folder is pretty real.