# Antivirus installed in a computer having two OSes

Tags: antivirus

I installed K7 total security.My computer has 8 partitions in total in the internal hard disk.  Obviously windows7 is installed in C partition.Other two partitions which are not hidden are- Movies(D:),Lenovo and Others(E:).   K7 total security can scan all these mentioned partitions i.e. C,D,E.But what about the other five partitions?I used 3 of these five hidden partitions to install Ubuntu13.10(Ubuntu shows it as- /,swap and /home partition).(i.e. I have two OS installed in my PC.)Other two hidden partitions are-system drive and LENOVO_PART.     I want to know whether my 5 hidden partitions are also protected from malware.I mean can K7 also scan these hidden partitions and bootloader or does K7 scan the whole computer regardless of partitions in windows?If not what will I have to do to protect ubuntu and other partitions from infection?

Answer (score 3):

Your antivirus can only see the partition Windows shows him. If Windows doesn't recognize the file system used it will not mount/list them. Hence your antivirus (nor virus, nor any kind of malware) cannot access it.

Ubuntu (and Linux in general) is quite secure without antivirus (of course no antivirus can protect you of scams or spam, so stop clicking girls!) for reasons mentioned countless times. You actually doesn't need an antivirus to protect Ubuntu from Windows viruses.

More related questions:

- [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/10373/169736)
- [Why aren't viruses an issue?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37198/169736)
- [What is the Ubuntu "built in virus protection"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/42284/169736)
- [Is there any guarantee that software from Launchpad PPAs is free from viruses and backdoor threats?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7662/169736)
- [What if I run a virus/trojan Windows EXE on Ubuntu with Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5031/169736)